# Making a layout fit views regardless of their order added to the layout?

Tags: java, android

I have a `LinearLayout` oriented vertically, and I'm trying to add three sub-views to it. One view is a small, 50px high view that just draws a box in it, the second view is a horizontal list of radio buttons, and the third view is a graph.

If I add the graph last, everything fits on screen, but if I add the graph first, it pushes everything off screen and it becomes the only view on the screen. The graph is a custom control of mine that wants to be as big as it can (its `onMeasure` function just returns the provided width and height), which I think is where the problem lies. But I want to keep it as big as possible, and have the layout fit the views regardless of their order added.

Is this possible? If so, how can I accomplish it? Ultimately, I'm trying to put the graph on top and the other two controls below it, but if I add the graph first it consumes the whole screen.

Here's the code I'm using to create the views. This is a school assignment and I can't use XML layouts for it. I've been assigned to make a control, which I've completed. I'm just trying to make a simple activity to show the control off.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        layout.addView(new MovingBox(this));

        RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(this);
        radioGroup.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);
        radioGroup.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        RadioButton button = new RadioButton(this);
        button.setText("Light");
        button.setLayoutParams(new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(RadioGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
        radioGroup.addView(button);

        button = new RadioButton(this);
        button.setText("Dark");
        button.setLayoutParams(new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(RadioGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
        radioGroup.addView(button);

        button = new RadioButton(this);
        button.setText("Colorful");
        button.setLayoutParams(new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(RadioGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
        radioGroup.addView(button);

        layout.addView(radioGroup);

        // If I move these next to lines just below layout.setOrientation(...) it becomes the only thing visible
        TweenerControl tw = new TweenerControl(this);
        layout.addView(tw);

        setContentView(layout);
    }
}
```

**Adding the graph last:** (everything fits but I'd like the graph on top)

[image: Adding the graph last]

**Adding the graph first:** (only the graph is visible)

[image: Adding the graph first]

Comment: Can you post the XML layouts you are using for these?

Comment: @brianestey: Currently, there is no XML. I'll edit it to post the code. I can't use XML for this assignment. `edit` Ok, code added.

Comment: consider using `layout_weight` for it, `layout.addView(tw, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, 1));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked on this more, and the solution I've come up with is to not use `LinearLayout` and use `RelativeLayout` instead. `RelativeLayout` tries to position and size things so they properly fit, whereas `LinearLayout` just gets the size of things and lays them out in top to bottom order, where items higher in the `LinearLayout` don't care about the sizing of items lower in the `LinearLayout`.